# SpringBoot JPA OneToMany return empty collection

Tags: spring-data-jpa, one-to-many

I'm learning SpringBoot JPA @OneToMany and @ManyToOne annotations. Now, ManyToOne works, but OneToMany don't work, the query returns an empty collection.

Here's the relationship of two entities:
(One)DetectUnit  contains (Many)Device

Facing this problem, I tried changing the @OneToMany propertities in many mays, still not work.

```
1. Device.java
//...
@ManyToOne(targetEntity=DetectUnit.class, fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
private DetectUnit detectUnit;
//...Getters, Setters


2. DetectUnit.java
//...
@OneToMany(targetEntity=Device.class, fetch=FetchType.EAGER) 
private List<Device> devices;
//...Getters, Setters
```

ManyToOne, worked, here's the query result:

```
[ 
 ...
 {
        "id": 5,
        "no": "ML002",
        "name": "梅李镇2号机",
        "deployTime": "2015-01-12",
        "detectUnit": { //works
            "id": 2,
            "no": "002",
            "name": "梅李检测站",
            "devices": []
        }
  },
 ...
]
```

OneToMany, not work, here's the query result:

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "no": "001",
        "name": "碧溪检测站",
        "devices": [] //not work ,empty ?
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "no": "002",
        "name": "梅李检测站",
        "devices": [] //not work, empty ?
    }
]
```

Any one got the same issue ?

Comment: Welcome @zhouyingge1104, I added an answer for this case and a brief explanation

Answer (score 1):

When you have a ManyToOne relationship like this:

```
@ManyToOne(targetEntity=DetectUnit.class, fetch= FetchType.EAGER)
private DetectUnit detectUnit;
```

For the OneToMany, in the DetectUnit, you specify the "mappedBy":

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "detectUnit", fetch= FetchType.EAGER)
private List<Device> devices;
```

Otherwise it will create a third table to relate both.

Comment: Thanks, you are right. But after many tries, I found that it's impossible to let OneToMany and ManyToOne both work. Only one of them work at the same time.    //@JsonManagedReference will let a property added to json,  
    //@JsonBackReference will ignore a property.     //@JsonManagedReference can only appear in one side of the relationship.

Comment: Maybe you can achieve something using //@JsonIdentityInfo or @JsonSerialize .. like here :https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-bidirectional-relationships-and-infinite-recursion